# jQuery UI Accordion activate

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm not getting how to do this, or if I can do this. I have a jQuery UI Accordion, multiple sections with each section containing multiple anchor tags each with a unique string id.

I'd like to be able to have the accordion open to where a particular element with a given id is. Like say id "item117". Can I use something like

```
$('#accordion').activate('activate','#item117');
```

or even

```
$('#accordion').activate('activate',117);
```

I've tried those and some variations but can't get it to go. In the case I was trying to get working, the accordion should've opened to the end of the second section.

---

I'm still not getting this, so maybe I'm doing something else wrong as well. I've stripped it down to an example page here: http://www.ofthejungle.com/testaccordion.php  Please have a look at it and its source.

Comment: Are you using the latest jQuery ui version? I believe the function used to be `change` not `activate`

Comment: Please note that this question was asked in 2009. When looking at the answers check the date of the response to see if its timely for you.

Answer (score 12):

have been over this too & found nice and universal solution 
    
- **emulate clicking** the header of required item by its id

```
$('#header-of-item-258').click();
```

that works everytime and anywhere not just accordion

Comment: I like this and use it for various odd menu needs. But I like to use the built in functionality where possible. So I've +1 you and @BTR :)

Answer (score 12):

From documentation:

```
// getter
var active = $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active" );

// setter
$( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active", 2 );
```

Answer (score 10):

for me worked

```
$("#accordion").accordion({active:"h3:last"})
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to call it using the function called `accordion`:

```
// Open the third set (zero based index)
$('#accordion').accordion('activate', 2);
```

To open a section containing a specific element, you would do something like this. *Note: you need to target the trigger that normally opens and closes the section. In the docs this is an `h3` element, your trigger element may be different, so change this accordingly.*

```
$('#accordion').accordion('activate', '#accordion > div:has(#item117) > h3');
```

Comment: is this documented in the jQuery UI API anywhere?

Comment: In jQuery UI 1.10.2 I get the error: `no such method 'activate' for accordion widget instance`

Comment: I think you mean active, not activate.

Answer (score 9):

This FINALLY worked for me:

```
$("#accordion").accordion("activate", $("#h3-id"));
```

NOTE!!! The id has to be that of the <h3> element you want to open up (in the default accordion setup).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with activating an accordion with #id. Sadly I hadn't found a way to this, so I've created a hack. I iterate through `div` elements in my accordion in order to get the index of interesting `div`. It looks like this:

```
acc = 'tab-you-are-interested-in';

// find corresponding accordion
act = 0;
panels = $('#accordion-element > div');
for (i=0; i<panels.length; i++) {
    if ( panels[i].id == acc ) {
        act = i;  
    }
}

$('#accordion-element').accordion('activate', act);
```

Comment: just what I was looking for this moment!

Answer (score 2):

When you click on header, it is h3 element and it opens the next div..that is functionality. Now, For activate , you need to provide index or the element. index might be different than your id. so i would use :

```
$('.selector').accordion('option', 'activate', $(h3#id));
```

If you have index, you can use that..But most of the cases , if you created accordion dynamically, it is not easy to get index of an id. You can find indices like this..

```
 var processingHeaders = $('#accordion h3');
 for (i = 0; i < processingHeaders.length; i++) {

        ids.push($(processingHeaders[i]).attr('id'));
        idsForLaterChecks.push($(processingHeaders[i]).attr('id')); 
    }
```

now i got ids.. 
using indexOf : find the index in the array and use it..

Note: // idsForLaterChecks is global

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery 1.9+ the:

```
$('#accordion').activate('activate', elementSelector);
```

is now:

```
$('#accordion').activate('option', 'active', elementSelector);
```

If you find it easier to use traversing methods, if you have HTML like this:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">Section</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p id="#item117" class="item">
            <a class="link-active" href="">Item 117</a>
        </p>            
    </div>
</div>
```

try this:

```
var myh3 = $('#item117').parent().prev('h3');
$('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active', myh3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#accordion').activate('#item117');
```

or

```
$('#accordion').activate(document.getElementById('item117'));
```

The correct syntax for activating an accordion is

```
$(".selector").activate(var index)
```

where index is String,Element,boolean,Number,JQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can also enable and disable the accordion like this:

```
// Add the class ui-state-disabled to the headers that you want disabled
$( ".whatyouwantdisabled" ).addClass("ui-state-disabled");
```

To reactivate the tab:

```
// Remove the class ui-state-disabled to the headers that you want to enable
$( ".whatyouwantenabled" ).removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
```

Comment: This does not work for me. The classes are add, however, accordion does not react.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way.

Include an ID="someId" in just each of the H3 header tags of the accordion and name the id's unique.

For example this id would be in series 'AccjA' the next h4 would be 'AccjB':

```
<h4 class="Accj" id="AccjA">
       <a href="#settings">A Fan?</a>
</h4>
```

Then activate whichever panel you wish with:

```
    $('#Accjoin').accordion('activate', '#AccjoinA')
```

I've used the above on a timeout to catch the attention of the user after the page is loaded with a 2 second delay using Ben Alman's ".doTimeout" function like:

```
$.doTimeout(2000, function () {
    $('#Accjoin').accordion('activate', '#AccjoinA')
});
```

Comment: The above doesn't work now with 1.9.
Like Jeremy Zerr points out now.  jQuery 1.9.+ has a different setter!!
http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active

Answer (score 0):

2024 solution.

Method 'activate' removed, instead of use 'option' method with option name 'active' (boolean or integer).

reference: https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active

For example initialization accordion with active header class.

```
$( ".acc_selector" ).accordion({
    header: "h3", 
    collapsible: true, 
    active: (function(){
            var iact = 0;
            $('.header_selector').each(function(idx){
               if($(this).hasClass('header_selector_active')){
                  iact = idx;   
               }
            });
            return iact;
    })(),
    heightStyle: "content",
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Whatch the jquery API

Activate the second content of the Accordion contained in .

```
$(".selector").activate(1)
```

Close all content parts of the accordion.

```
$(".selector").activate(false)
```

Activate the first element matching the given expression.

```
$(".selector").activate("a:first")
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$('#collapseOne').collapse('toggle');
```