# How do I initialize <sj:accordion> in struts2 using JavaScript?

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-plugin

I am developing a Struts2 application and have been using <sj:accordion> (https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/AccordionTag).

Until now, I have been initializing it on my jsp page by hardcoding the value I want in the tags but is there anyway to initialize it using JavaScript?

Here is what I'm trying to solve. I have an accordion that I initialize using (all values are hard-coded):

```
<sj:accordion
    id="accordionremote"
    active="0"
            />
```

The '**active**' element allows me to decide which <sj:accordionItem> is active/open on page load. Is there any other way to initialize the active element or which <sj:accordionItem> is open on page-load without hard-coding it?

I have tried using **$("#accordion").accordion('activate', 0);** as described by [jquery accordion: activate option using Struts <sj:accordion>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105483/jquery-accordion-activate-option-using-struts-sjaccordion) but it does not work when I place it inside a <script> element.

Comment: I dont get any error.

Comment: Actually I think you can assign an OGNL expression as the value of `active` e.g. `active="{#parameters.activeWindow}"` so it can be changed dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! You have to use `$("#accordion").accordion({active : 1});`

```javascript
<sj:accordion id="accordion"
              heightStyle="content"
              animate="true"
              collapsible="true"
              active="0"
              onCreateTopics="initAccd"

              >
    <sj:accordionItem title="item1"></sj:accordionItem>
    <sj:accordionItem title="item2"></sj:accordionItem>
</sj:accordion>

<script>

    //going to initialize the accordion
    $.subscribe("initAccd", function (event, data){
        //activate the 2nd item i.e. item2
        $("#accordion").accordion({active : 1});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way to initialize the active element or which  is open on page-load without hard-coding it?

```js
$("#accordionremote").accordion('option', 'active', 0);
```