# In jQuery, how to remove all occurrences of a CSS class, and add it once to a specific sibling of the tag's parent's parent?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an accordion menu structure to display projects for a client. Each project also has two other links, not within the accordion. When of those links is clicked, the accordion resets to the default open position, the first project. Client doesn't want this: the active project should remain open in the accordion. Quite logical.

This is the structure:

```
<div class="ui-accordion">
    <h3>clickable title for accordion items</h3>
    <ul>
         <li><a></a></li>
         <li><a class="active"></a></li>
         <li><a></a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3>clickable title for accordion items</h3>
    <ul>
         <li><a></a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3>clickable title for accordion items</h3>
    <ul>
         <li><a></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So the `h3` above the `ul` containing the `li` containing the `a.active` should get the 
class `ui-state-active` and any other `h3` should have that class removed.

I figured out that I can use

`.addClass('ui-state-active').siblings().removeClass('ui-state-active');`

...but I don't know how to target that `h3` above the `ul`. Any help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: Anton's code works perfectly, but didn't solve the problem. There's more to the accordion code than just changing a class, apparently.
I tried going through the API, it looks like option active might help: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active

But doing this

    $('a.active').closest('ul')
    .prev() 
    .accordion( "option", "active");

...doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You could add an attribute to each "a" that refers to its "h3". Eg:

```
<a data-h3="h3one"></a>
```

Would refer back to:

```
<h3 id="h3one"></h3>
```

Then your jQuery could start with:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
  var h3 = $('h3[id=' + $(this).attr('data-h3') + ']');
  // etc....
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('a.active').closest('ul')
             .prev() 
             .addClass('ui-state-active')
             .siblings('h3')
             .removeClass('ui-state-active');
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$( "div.ui-accordion" ).accordion("activate", $('a.active').closest('ul').prev());
```

Partly inspired through this: [jQuery UI Accordion activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899307/jquery-ui-accordion-activate)
Thanks for the help!