# show hide accordion tabs depending on php variable session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to show amount of accordion tabs depending on php variable present in session

I have a simple accordion *(see bellow)*.

And I have a switch statement of variables *(see bottom)*, I am trying to work out a easy way to display some of sections depending on the variable active withing the switch statement.

**for example**

if `var1` present hide `section2` and `section3`.

if `var2` present hide `section2`.

**One Idea I had (First Idea)**

I could pop different accordions into different PHTML pages and include depending on the statement, but this is repeating code many times, I feel like there should be a more efficient method where I hide and show accordion tabs depending on the variable.

**A different Idea I had (Second Idea)**

give each section a class, then using the case statement hide the class

```
 <?php
        switch ($_SESSION['buy_test_session']) {
            case "var1":
             //--//
                break;
            case "var2":
                ?>
                <style type="text/css">
                    .section1 {display:none;}
                    .section3 {display:none;}
                </style>
        <?php
                break;
            case "var3":
                //--/
                break;
```

*If All else fails my Second Idea will work and ill go with that*

**My Current Code**

***accordion***

```
 <div id="accordion">

  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
   text
    </p>
  </div>

  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    text
    </p>
  </div>

  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
   text
    </p>
  </div>

  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
     <p>
   text
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

***Switch Statement***

```
 <?php
            switch ($_SESSION['buy_test_session']) {
                case "var1":
                  //hide section 2 and 3//
                    break;
                case "var2":
                    //hide section 2//
                    break;
                case "var3":
                  //--//
                    break;
                case "var4":
                         //--//
                    break;

                default:
                    echo "Normal";
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Try looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899307/jquery-ui-accordion-activate

Comment: Thanks @Dean.DePue ill investigate into the solution

Answer (score 0):

simple fix, just populate each tab with a class and depending on the session hide.

```
<?php
    switch ($_SESSION['buy_test_session']) {
        case "var1":
         //--//
            break;
        case "var2":
            ?>
            <style type="text/css">
                .section1,.section3 {display:none;}
            </style>
    <?php
            break;
        case "var3":
            //--/
            break;
```